# Is it possible to buy all the skills?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

As there are quite a few skills available in the game, is it actually possible to buy all the skills?

Below I have included a screenshot of my level 9 skill tree.

[image: My lv9 skilltree]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As killing enemies earns experience points, which eventually lead to a level up and a skill point reward, it is a safe bet that you can earn enough skill points to buy all the available skills in the game, by killing enemies and completing quests.

This is reported on the Twinfinite site also.

> it looks like the max level cap is level 50. By this point, you’ll
> have already earned enough skill points to unlock all of the available
> Skills.
>
> ..
>
> Upon reaching level 50, you’ll also earn a bronze trophy. It’s the
> final level-related trophy, so it’s a good sign that this is the max
> level cap in the game.

Ref: [twinfinite.net Max level cap](http://twinfinite.net/2017/02/horizon-zero-dawn-max-level-cap-what-it-is/)

The top row of skills all cost 1 skill point, the whole row costs 9 points. The second row skills cost 2 points, with a total of 18, and the last two rows of skills all cost 3 points each, totalling 54 point for both rows.

So in all you'll need to earn 81 skill points to buy all the skills. Might be 80 in total, as I think Silent Strike is given for free.

As mentioned by [@Shaz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/116363/shaz) in the comments, there is also a trophy for unlocking all the skills.
[image: Learn all skills bronze trophy]

Comment: I will update this answer in my lunchbreak when I can access the game and calculate the total skill points and add the cost tiers in as well.

Comment: Are these skills upgradeable?

Comment: No, they are not. They are a single buy and that's it.

Comment: Does each level gained = 1 skill point earned? Reading this as a person interested in (but have not yet played) the game, you mention that the max level is 50, but you need 80 skill points to fill the grid. Where are the other 30 or so points coming from?

Comment: @king14nyr You get skill points from completing quests as well I think. I'm level 9 and I've already filled the whole top row and one from the second row.

Comment: To supplement this answer - look at the trophies/achievements for the game. One of them is to unlock all skills.

Comment: @Shaz Yep, good point. That's mentioned in the linked article, but I failed to quote it. I'll add that.

Comment: @DavidYell: The quote you added is about a trophy for achieving level 50, not a trophy for unlocking all skills.

Comment: I got all of them, you can easily get all skills because the game also rewards you one skill point for certains quests (some main quests and some sidequests).
In order to buy all the skills you have to reach level 50 and do some of these quests (but not all of them as there are more points to get than you can spend).

Comment: To give more info: Main quests give a skill point at it seems every major event. Unlocking Tallnecks seem to give 1 skill point too (each).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to unlock all the skills; here is the proof:

[image: Horizon Zero Dawn - all skills unlocked]

This is with the Frozen Wilds expansion pack included<sup>1</sup> but not played through<sup>2</sup>.

To get it I:

1. levelled up to the maximum (level 60).
2. played all quests and side quests of Horizon Zero Dawn (excluding Frozen Wilds). This includes all the Hunting Grounds missions getting all Blazing <s>Saddles</s> Suns.
3. got all the [collectables](http://www.powerpyx.com/horizon-zero-dawn-all-collectible-locations-guide/)<sup>3</sup>. You get skill points when you sell Banuk Figures, Metal Flowers and Ancient Vessels.

Additional note: when I had one skill (costing three skill points) to "buy", I had seven skill points. When I bought it, I "lost" those four extra skill points.

---

<sub>1 I have the Complete Edition.</sub>

<sub>2 That is, I have played through the entire Horizon Zero Dawn main campaign but none of Frozen Wilds.</sub>

<sub>3 Training Dummies only add a badge, no skill points.</sub>